# Reading custom ethernet frames with ESP-IDF on ESP32

Tags: tcp, ethernet, esp32, esp-idf

I am using ESP-IDF to programm an ESP32 (Olimex ESP32-POE).
I have written a program which can send out broadcast ethernet frames with a custom ethertype using `esp_eth_transmit()`.

Now I want to make it receive frames (unicast) with the same ethertype, but don't know how this works.

Also I want to have a little web interface, so I need TCP/IP.

I have a TCP/IP stack running using `esp_netif_attach(eth_netif, esp_eth_new_netif_glue(eth_handle))`, but I am not sure, how to receive these custom ethernet frames in addition to the TCP/IP handling.
Can someone provide a sample?

I found out that I can use `esp_eth_update_input_path(eth_handle, my_stack_input, (void *)true);` to check incoming frames, but how to chainlink this to the TCP/IP stack?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am stuck on the exact same point. I am sending raw ethernet packets successfully, but can't receive without screwing up the TCP/IP stack. If there is a way to get the packet handler function pointer one can forward the IP packets to the IP stack and monitor for raw packets that I am interested in...

Comment: Found the solution: ESP-IDF has a NETIF L2TAP library that does exactly what I need. Sending and receiving via standard open/close/read/write with ioctl to set the frame types you are interested in.