# ESP32 in WIFI STA mode: how to intercept incoming ARPs? not just IP packets

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, lwip

I have a problem with an ESP32 device configured as WIFI STA. I have intercepted the incoming WIFI packets esp_wifi_internal_reg_rxcb" but I only receive IP packets, not ARP or other packets.

I have tried in ESP AP mode and with esp_wifi_internal_reg_rxcb I can receive ARP and other packets but in STA mode I can't. I have been digging in the lwip source code and esp-idf framework source code but it is too complex for me. I understand the posible solution may not be supported or clever, or stop working in a future esp-idf release, etc.. It is ok for me at this point.

Thank you for any help!
Antonio

Comment: Check info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68080303/reading-custom-ethernet-frames-with-esp-idf-on-esp32 if you get frames, you can filter just arp frames.